# Линковщик не хочет линковать

Tags: c++, линковка

Линковщик выдаёт ошибку `undefined reference to '_imp__lib_test@8'`. Если использовать nm то можно найти что в библиотеке есть функция `_imp__lib_test` но она без @8. Может ли это быть причиной undefined reference и если да то как избавиться от @8

Comment: Функция экспортирована как `extern "C"`, а вы ее пытаетесь линковать, как С++ функцию.

Comment: Что надо сделать чтобы правильно линковать? Проект использует cmake

Comment: Нужно использовать один и тот же заголовок. И для сборки библиотеки, и для сборки приложения.

Answer (score 2):

func@Х это формат VC/VC++/mingw для C функций __stdcall с общим размером аргументов равным 8 байтам.

Причина это защита от stack corruption так как stdcall должен очищать stack а в cdecl это должен делать то кто вызвал процедуру.

В вашем случае возможно эта защита и срабатывает, если в DLL функция cdecl (по умолчанию будет без типа вызова) a в коде программы она определена с stdcall/WINAPI.

Comment: А как тогда изменить соглашение? Дело в том что и программа и библиотека находятся в одном проекте почему собрались с разными соглашениями о вызовах я не знаю